# How to add a newsletter popup only on first visit?

Tags: magento2, newsletter

In Magento2, using alpine & tailwind.css, I want to add a newsletter popup as the customer reaches the homepage on the first visit.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: may be this link will help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176716/magento-2-popup-model-need-to-open-only-one-time-on-whole-webiste-after-login-or#:~:text=to%20a%20client.-,%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22popup%2Dmodal%22%3E,-%3Clink%20rel

Comment: I've checked this before, it seems the solution but how to handle it with alpine? Or can I directly use the knockout script in the link?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this module and customise according to your needs.
https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-newsletter-popup

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below module

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-newsletter-popup/
https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-newsletter-popup

and for the first time load can set cookies with the help of below functions

```
        function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
              var d = new Date();
              d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
              var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
              document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
          }

          function getCookie(cname) {
              var name = cname + "=";
              var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
              for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                  var c = ca[i];
                  while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                      c = c.substring(1);
                  }
                  if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                  }
              }
              return "";
          }

          function checkCookie(cname) {
              var user=getCookie(cname);
              if (user != "") {
                  return "1";
              } else {
                  return "0";
              }
          }

 var popupShow = checkCookie("mobile_login_popup_show");
                if(popupShow != "1") {
                   // your popup load code
               
                    setCookie("mobile_login_popup_show", 1, 1);
                }
```